# Dropdown menu not opening on click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

The dropdown menu inside navbar is not opening on click. 
Here's HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" href="brand logo.png" type="image/gif">
    <title>Special Education Notes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#homeImage"><img src="brand logo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="menu-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#about">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Notes
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: 20px;" href="bedspl.php">B.Ed Special Education</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: 20px;" href="dedspl.php">D.Ed. Special Education</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#contact-us" aria-disabled="true">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" aria-disabled="true">Upload</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><span class="nav-link"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Special-Education-Notes-113164063713889/" target="_blank" style="color: white; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here's the javascript code:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function() {
});
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function() {
});
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/n2jq7uLx/

I want my navbar to close after selecting the link but it seems to not working on the dropdown menu inside the navbar.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown menu guard is realized as a html anchor element (`a`). IN the intializer code, the same handler is attached as is for the leaf anchors that implement actual navigation.

Solution:
Do not attach the handler to this element.

Coding:
The linked fiddle has several problems:

- It does not include jQuery, while jQuery is used
- The handlers use the `.collapse` method that is not defined.
- The use of `.hide` (which was probably intended) does not work here because the `.navbar-collapse` element whose css is to be modified has the `display` property value marked with `!important` in its css overriding the settings produced by the click handler.
- (The click handler *might* be set at the wrong point in time as it is not explicitly sync'ed with the dom tree creation ( I haven't checked this though and haven't researched this any more but wrapped the handler assignments with the jquery `.ready` method ))

The code below uses the more specific css selector that controls the `display: flex!important` css property assignment to the navigation bar and filters the dropdown menu guard from the elements the handler is registered with. The element to be hidden is found in a bottom-up traversal starting at the element receiving the element which might be a tad more efficient than querying it by its css class (no benchmarks though).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-collapse a').not(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(eve) {
       $(eve.target).closest(".navbar-expand-sm .navbar-collapse").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" href="brand logo.png" type="image/gif">
    <title>Special Education Notes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#homeImage"><img src="brand logo.png" alt="logo" style="width: 70px;"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="menu-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#about">About Us<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Notes
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: 20px;" href="http://www.google.de">B.Ed Special Education</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size: 20px;" href="http://www.google.de">D.Ed. Special Education</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#contact-us" aria-disabled="true">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: 20px;" href="#" aria-disabled="true">Upload</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"><span class="nav-link"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Special-Education-Notes-113164063713889/" target="_blank" style="color: white; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It works fine but all navbar items disappear after selecting any item.

Comment: Yes, they do. You wrote that you want your navbar to close. If you want to limit the effect to parts of the navbar, change the selector in the `.closest` method or dismiss this way selecting elements altogether and go for the standard `$(<your selector>)` idiom.

Comment: Sorry but I am fairly new to JavaScript, so I couldn't clearly understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the correct code:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a:not(.dropdown-toggle)').click(function(){
      $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
```